# How to transfer control from service to post method in servlets?

Tags: java, servlets

I have written the following code in service and post methods

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();
    p.println("<html><body>");
    p.println("<form action = roomlog2 method = post>");
    p.println("<input type = submit value = back>");
    p.println("</form>");
    p.println("</body></html>");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.sendRedirect("homepage.html");
 }
```

But when i executed the code and click the back button the post method is not executing. I am getting following exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

why the post method not redirecting to the "homepage.html"?why i am getting the exception?Kindly someone can tell me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your implementation of the `service()` method, or have it call `super.service()`. That's how `doPost()` gets called. At present you're not calling it at all.